# Login with yahoo in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, yahoo-api

I want to integrate login with yahoo in my swift project. 
I am using below code/sample for the same. [Yahoo-Login](https://github.com/amitdagar/YahooLogin_ContactList) .
I have created my app in Yahoo developer and generated secret keys. It opens the yahoo login page but the issues are in callback `URL`. What should be the callback `URL` for an `iOS` app that redirects the user to the app with the user data which has been retrieved?

-Thanks in advance,
 Aakil

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Yahoo is using a standard Oauth login, and the code you're using is standard Oauth (might want to look into using the built-in SFAuthenticationSession/ASWebAuthenticationSession class) setting up your app to respond to a specific redirect is easy. Just go into your Project settings, select your target, go to the Info tab, go to URL Types. Add a URL scheme. Now your app will respond to redirects for that scheme.

So for example, if I use a scheme "mycoolapp" I would use a redirect like: "mycoolapp://loginfromyahoo"

The "loginfromyahoo" path can be whatever you want, you can use that to provide additional information to your app, or leave it off.

More details [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app).